# Does this sentence miss a "to" after "assign"

Tags: passive-voice, prepositional-phrases, indirect-objects, thematic-role

Suppose this sentence, I've found it in a scholarly technical article about Android.

> Based on criteria, such as the requested permissions, apps are assigned a security type.

In my opinion, this sentence needs a *to* after word *assigned*. Something like this

> Based on criteria, such as the requested permissions, apps are assigned **to** a security type.

So, Is my second sentence correct? if so, could you please tell my under what circumstances, I can omit *to* after verbs.

For example, can I omit *to* from this sentence `He went to the park.` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In computer writing in general,  phrases of the form "**X is assigned *a* Y**" can be translated into this pseudo-code:

**X.relevantProperty = Y**

That is, the "relevantProperty" property of object "X" is assigned value Y.

If we **assign X *to* a Y**, it could be translated into this pseudo-code:

**(List) Y

    Y.append(X)**

And finally, if we **"assign Y to X**"

**X = Y**

Comment: GREAT answer, now it's making full of sense, thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand what is happening here. The security type is not a category in which the app is placed, but a property which is given to the app.

*Assign* has the same functional relationships as the verb *give*. There are three roles:

- a GIVER
- a GIFT
- a RECIPIENT

In an ordinary declarative sentence the GIVER is the subject and the GIFT is the direct object. There are two ways of designating the RECIPIENT:

- The RECIPIENT may be cast as the **indirect object**. In this case, the indirect object can be identified by its position between the verb and the direct object:

  > John gave **Mary** a box of chocolates.
  >   The Army assigned **Jack** a rifle.
  >   The system assigns **apps** a security type.
- The RECIPIENT may be cast as the object of the preposition *to*. In this case, the **preposition phrase** is placed after the direct object:

  > John gave a box of chocolates **to Mary**.
  >   The Army assigned a rifle **to Jack**.
  >   The system assigns a security type **to apps**.

  This alternative marking usually occurs with a 'heavy' RECIPIENT, one with a lot of words; this makes the direct object easier to recognize, because it follows the verb immediately.

Either the RECIPIENT or the GIFT may become the subject of a passive sentence. In this case the subject moves to the front, leaving other in place after the verb. When the RECIPIENT becomes the subject, this is straightforward:

> Mary was given a box of chocolates.
>   Jack was assigned a rifle.
>   Apps are assigned a security type.

But when the GIFT becomes the subject, the RECIPIENT **must** in Present Day English be marked with *to*.

> A box of chocolates was given to Mary.
>   A rifle was assigned to Jack.
>   A security type is assigned to apps.

Knowing this pattern allows the reader to perceive immediately which entity is the GIFT and which the RECIPIENT. Thus, there is no question in your example of *to* being 'omitted'; it should never have been there. Your rewrite would reverse the relationships: the security type would become the RECIPIENT of the app, and the app would become the GIFT, something which becomes a property or member of the type.

Answer (score 0):

Adding *to* actually changes the meaning of the sentence!

> Apps are assigned a security type.

Means that a security type is assigned *to* each app.

So

> Apps are assigned to a security type.

Means the exact opposite of the original.

Compare it to this different but similar example:

> The children are all given a name.
>   *The children are all given *to* a name.